# External font not applied by CSS

Tags: javafx-8

I'm trying to create icon buttons. I've downloaded them from [flaticon.com](http://flaticon.com) and had them exported as icon font files, which includes a TTF file.

In my css file I specify the external font as:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: flaticon;
  src: url('/flaticon/flaticon.ttf');
}
```

I've defined a button class that should use this font as follows:

```
.flaticon-button {
   -fx-font-size: 90px;
   -fx-font-family: flaticon;
   -fx-padding: 10px;
}
```

My code applies the styleclass as follows:

```
Button button = new Button("\ue000");
button.getStyleClass().add("flaticon-button");
```

But unfortunately it doesn't show the expected icon.
When I load the font in my code and set it explicitly the correct icon is shown:

```
Font font = Font.loadFont(this.getClass().getResource("/flaticon/flaticon.ttf").toExternalForm() , 90d);
Button button = new Button("\ue000");
button.setFont(font);
```

I'm obviously overlooking something small, but despite how many examples I browse on the internet, or how long I stare at Oracle's CSS documentation I can't see what.

So, what is wrong with my CSS declaration and usage?

Comment: Does it work with the full URL? `http://...`

Comment: I don't know, as I don't know the full URL. The font file is generated containing only the icons I selected. The font itself is embedded in the application's resources.

Maybe the src url expects the font file to be on disk this way?

Comment: Start with the full local URL: `file:///C:/ ...` and chop pieces off the front until it fails.  Careful with capitalisation as well, make sure it matches.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of rossum, I realized it it might have something to do with the URL not resolving to the class, as Class.getResource() does.

By loading the font in the main, before it is references by the code, it seems to be resolved. I guess there is no other way, but it seems to be a bit of a hack to me.